# If $f=g$ on $S$ then $f=g$ on whole $C$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> If a rational functions $f,g$ coincide on an infinite set $S\subset C$, i.e.  $f=g$ on $S$, where $C$ is a smooth curve, defined by for example $\varphi(x,y,z)=0$, then $f=g$.

Which theorem was that ? There is an analogue for analytic functions in complex analysis but here I'm searching for a theorem in algebraic geometry

Comment: By a rational function do you mean a ratio of polynomials? Sorry I am ignorant in algebraic geometry.

Comment: WLOG, may assume $f$ and $g$ are polynomials. Then $\{f-g=0\}$ is a closed set of $C$, which is either $C$ or finitely many points.